# repeatWhen based off of the event that triggered the completion

Tags: rx-java

I've got the following code to modify my source observable so that it will disconnect and reconnect when the applications status switches between ENABLED and DISABLED.

However, if my sourceObservable itself has a situation where it calls complete, I suspect it will immediately reconnect due to this transformer's repeatWhen if the application status is still ENABLED.

Is there an elegant way of solving this by perhaps grouping the takeUntil and repeatWhen so that they don't catch any complete events coming from above?

N.B. applicationStatusObservable repeats its last value on request.

Help is much appreciated :)

```
/**
 * Transforms the source observable so that it defers initial subscription until the service becomes available,
 * unsubscribes when the service becomes unavailable, and resubscribes when the service becomes available again.
 */
public class AvailabilityTransformer<T> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T> {

    private final Observable<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatusObservable;

    AvailabilityTransformer(final Observable<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatusObservable) {
        this.applicationStatusObservable = applicationStatusObservable;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(final Observable<T> sourceObservable) {
        final Observable<ApplicationStatus> applicationEnabledObservable =
                applicationStatusObservable.filter(applicationStatus -> applicationStatus == ENABLED);
        final Observable<ApplicationStatus> applicationDisabledObservable =
                applicationStatusObservable.filter(applicationStatus -> applicationStatus != ENABLED);
        return sourceObservable
                .takeUntil(applicationDisabledObservable) // Unsubscribe whenever the application is disabled
                .repeatWhen(repeatObservable -> repeatObservable.flatMap(repeat ->
                        applicationEnabledObservable.flatMap(applicationStatus -> just(repeat)))) // Resubscribe when enabled again
                .delaySubscription(applicationEnabledObservable.first()); // Delay the initial subscription until the application is first enabled
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the applicationStatusObservable hot or cold? So, what are you trying to achieve with AvailabilityTransformer? I don't get it properly.

Comment: applicationStatusObservable is cold with a replay(1).refCount() - in any case it will always return the current application status, and if the observer stays subscribed, notifications of any changes to the application status.

The idea is if the application is disabled, we cancel the source observable subscription. When it becomes enabled again, it will resubscribe to the source observable.

Comment: Looking into the implementation of OperatorTakeUntil and OnSubscribeDelay etc. I think it's probably more suitable to write this as an Operator rather than a Transformer.. closing for now.

Answer (score 0):

He,

it took me some time to understand what you are doing. I hope I finally got it. You have a hot observable isApplicationAvailable which will tell the subscriber if the application is enabled or disabled (true/false). You have other observables, which are doing some work (maybe hot/ cold) and want them only to produce values, if the observable isApplicationAvailable return true. If for some reaseon the application becomes disabled, the observables should not generate any values.

I use RxJava2 for testing.

In this example stringObservable will only passe down values to the subscriber, if the observable isApplicationActive return true.

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    Subject<Boolean> isApplicationActive = BehaviorSubject.<Boolean>create()
            .toSerialized();

    Observable<Boolean> isApplicationActiveObservable = isApplicationActive
            .hide()
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("isApplicationActive: " + s));

    isApplicationActive.onNext(false);

    Thread.sleep(1_000);

    Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.interval(1_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(Objects::toString)
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("NextIntervalValue"))
            .compose(createSwitchMapCompose(isApplicationActiveObservable));

    stringObservable.subscribe(s -> {
        System.out.println("stringObservable: " + s);
    });

    Thread.sleep(2_000);

    isApplicationActive.onNext(true);

    Thread.sleep(2_000);

    isApplicationActive.onNext(false);

    Thread.sleep(2_000);

    isApplicationActive.onNext(true);

    Thread.sleep(6_000);

    isApplicationActive.onNext(false);

    Thread.sleep(20_000);
}

private ObservableTransformer<String, String> createSwitchMapCompose(Observable<Boolean> isApplicationActiveObservable) {
    return upstream -> upstream.switchMap(s -> isApplicationActiveObservable.take(1).flatMap(aBoolean -> {
                if (aBoolean) {
                    return Observable.just(s);
                }
                return Observable.empty();
            })
    );
}
```